# Non-essential Angular promises

Tags: angularjs, asynchronous, angular-promise

I'm trying to rewrite the code for http://m.amsterdamfoodie.nl in a more modern style. Basically single page Angular app downloads a set of restaurants with locations and places them on a map. If the user is the Amsterdam area then the user's location is added too, as are the distances to places.

At present I manage the asynchronous returns using a lot of `if (relevant object from other async call exists) then do next step`. I'd like to make more use of promises would be better.

So, flow control should be:

- Start ajax data download, and geolocation call
- **if geolocation returns first**, store coords for later
- once ajax data is downloaded

  - **if geolocation available**

    - calculate distances to each restaurant, and pass control to rendering code
  - else pass control immediately to render code
- **if geolocation resolves later**, calculate distances and re-render

The patterns I find on the internet assume that all async calls must return successfully before continuing, whereas my geolocation call can fail (or return a location far from amsterdam) and that's OK. Is there a trick I could use in this scenario or are the conditional statements really the way to go?

Comment: Your promise can still `resolve` successfully even if the data is "negative" or non-existent - treat this as a successful outcome. Treat `reject` similarly to a `catch` in `try/catch` blocks, and handle fatal exceptions.

Comment: How do I check that whether a geolocaiton promise has resolved after I have the restaurant data. If it hasn't resolved I am not going to wait for it (as the result may well be that the person is not in Amsterdam anyway).

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but you can resolve it whether you have obtained the data or got the negative result. That would be the input into your next step.

Comment: What I was looking for was something more elegant than the three `if` statements now in bold that leveraged the flow control of angular $http and $q. That may be wishful thinking?

Answer (score 0):

Every time you use `.then`, you essentially create a new promise based on the previous promise and its state. You can use that to your advantage (and you should).

You can do something along the lines of:

```
function getGeolocation() {
  return $http.get('/someurl').then(
    function resolveHandler(response) {
      // $http.X resolves with a HTTP response object.
      // The JSON data is on its `data` attribute
      var data = response.data;

      // Check if the data is valid (with some other function).
      // By this, I mean e.g. checking if it is "far from amsterdam",
      // as you have described that as a possible error case
      if(isValid(data)) {
        return data;
      }
      else {
        return null;
      }
    },
    function rejectHandler() {
      // Handle the retrieval failure by explicitly returning a value
      // from the rejection handler. Null is arbitrarily chosen here because it
      // is a falsy value. See the last code snippet for the use of this
      return null;
    }
  );
}

function getData() {
  return $http.get('/dataurl').then(...);
}
```

and then use [`$q.all`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q#all) on both promises, which in turn creates a new promise that resolves as soon as all the given promises have resolved.

**Note**: In [Kris Kowal's Q](https://github.com/kriskowal/q), which [Angular's $q service](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q) is based on, you could use the `allSettled` method, which does almost the same as `all`, but resolves when all promises are **settled** (fulfilled or rejected), and not only if all promises are **fulfilled**. Angular's $q does not provide this method, so you can instead work your way around this by explicitly making the failed http request resolve anyways.

So, then you can do something like:

```
$q.all([getData(), getGeolocation()])
.then(function(data, geolocation) {
  // `data` is the value that getData() resolved with,
  // `geolocation` is the value that getGeolocation() resolved with.
  // Check the documentation on `$q.all` for this.
  if(geolocation) {
    // Yay, the geolocation data is available and valid, do something
  }

  // Handle the rest of the data
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm missing something... but since you have no dependencies between the two async calls, I don't see why you can't just follow the logic you outlined:

```
var geoCoordinates = null;
var restaurants = null;
var distances = null;

getRestaurantData()
  .then(function(data){
     restaurants = data;
     if (geoCoordinates) {
        distances = calculate(restaurants, geoCoordinates);
     }
     // set $scope variables as needed
});

getGeoLocation()
  .then(function(data){
     geoCoordinates = data;
     if (restaurants){
        distances = calculate(restaurants, geoCoordinates)
     }
     // set $scope variables as needed
  });
```